# why javascript ignores changes in default text of the textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dom

I can't understand why javascript ignores changes of the default text of the textbox?

More details:
The textbox has default text as 'Search'. When client tries to submit the search form with the default text, it should return false and get focus back to the textbox.

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="search rnd" ID="SearchBox" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="searchForm" MaxLength="100" CssClass="text" Text="Search" onfocus="if ( this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = 'Search'; }"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="searchForm" CssClass="btn-search" ToolTip="Search the Website" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="if ( document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').value = 'Search') { document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').style.background = 'yellow'; document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').focus(); return false; } " />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="hdn rf" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtSearch" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</asp:Panel>
```

Please someone help me!

Comment: Can you please explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning instead of comparing.

Change: `if ( document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').value = 'Search')`

To `if ( document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').value == 'Search')`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working well , I just put the code in a function and called it `OnClientClick`

you also forgot to use `==` instead of `=` in your `if` statement
try this :

```
   <asp:Panel CssClass="search rnd" ID="SearchBox" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="searchForm" MaxLength="100" CssClass="text" Text="Search"
     onfocus="if ( this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = 'Search'; }"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ValidationGroup="searchForm" CssClass="btn-search" ToolTip="Search the Website" 
    OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick=" validateTextbox()" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="hdn rf" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtSearch" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</asp:Panel>


<script>

    function validateTextbox() {

        if (document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').value == 'Search') {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').style.background = 'yellow';

            document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').focus();

            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```